# Intellij idea hotkey to open project (execution context) within run anything popup

Tags: intellij-idea, hotkeys

Is there a hotkey combination to open the "Project" menu from the "run anything" popup?
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `tab`?

Comment: @Justinas, yes, doesn't work on my mac (

Comment: Please follow the related issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-227626